# Multiple application under single project in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

How to create multiple application under single project in Angular 6? In new angular.json file, there is no `"app":[]` array, where before we used to create/add multiple applications manually. Also there is no proper documentation I found at this stage, which elaborate how to create multiple application in single project. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: But there is a projects array. And there is this command: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-application

Comment: Hey did you manage to sovle and do you have a sample project i can look at

Comment: @Kay Please checkout martzcodes answer, I have follow those steps in my project. As we've mention previously, project structure is still not up to the mark but this is what Angular team provide at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

Like @JB Nizet said... you can use `generate application` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-application)

```
ng generate application <application-name>
```

to generate an application in the projects folder, and then serve it using

```
ng serve --project <application-name>
```

Similarly, you can create component libraries using `ng generate library` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-library)

```
ng generate library <library-name>
```

For common components used between projects.  Both of which get installed into the `/projects` folder unless you changed the projects root when doing `ng new`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I used `ng generate application <name>` to create new app inside my existing project, but now I am having some problem in project structure. When I created my project, It follows this structure;
project-name -> project-name -> src -> app, Now when I create through ng generate, It create new "project" directory and inside that there is new app. So I got one app in "project" folder and another outside that folder, which in my opinion is not a good structure. I obviously can't move my original app inside project folder. Is there any other way?

Comment: Funny enough... but I created this exact issue on github the other day: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11402  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090592/how-to-create-a-mono-repo-project-structure-with-angular-cli-6-x

Answer (score 5):

If you have a project with multiple applications, use angular upgrade guide (https://update.angular.io/) instructions to upgrade your application. One of the step while performing upgrade is to run

```
ng upgrade @angular/cli
```

(once you upgrade your @angular/cli to v6+). This will generate new angular.json file using your existing angular-cli.json file for multiple applciations.

[Upgrade Angular CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKJUt.png)

### OR

Manually edit your angular.json to add new application to the existing project. Editing JSON file for [Another Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwmF0.png).

```
ng serve --project="second-app"

ng build --prod --project="second-app" // build prod app
```

Comment: No need to do that manually now, They gave us `ng generate` command to create new application. But the project structure in which it is created is not proper and little bit confusing too, in my honest opinion. Please read comments in @martzcodes reply for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Create a workspace with `--createApplication="false"`

```
ng new MultipleApps --createApplication="false"
cd MultipleApps
```

use `ng generate application` to add as many apps

```
ng generate application app1
ng generate application app2
```

To run the app use the `ng serve`

```
ng serve app1
```

Source [Angular multiple projects](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-multiple-apps-in-one-project/)

Answer (score 0):

To get my application working I removed everything from the main *app.component.html* file except for the

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>.
```

Then I added a route to my *app-routing.module.ts* file:

```
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'newApp'}
```

with nothing in the main app.component the application will automatically redirect to your 'newApp'